# sqlite3 foreign key mismatch when trying to delete table records

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables created with the following sql statments:

```
CREATE TABLE `videos` (
`id `   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`file_name` TEXT,
`fps`   INTEGER,
`folder_path`   TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE `video_shot_hashes` (
`id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`video_id`  INTEGER,
`pos`   INTEGER,
`time_pos`  TEXT,
`hash`  TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(`video_id`) REFERENCES `videos`(`id`) on delete cascade
);
```

now when I try to delete all records in the videos table using the following SQL statment:

```
delete from videos
```

I get :

> foreign key mismatch - "video_shot_hashes" referencing "videos": delete from videos

what I want is to force delete all records records in both tables how to that?

Comment: Delete the space after id: `id ` in the create statement of videos.

Comment: @forpas I wnat to delete the records in the both tables without re-creating them can you help?

Comment: `delete from videos` doesn't work now?

Comment: @forpas no it is not, I get foreign key mismatch - "video_shot_hashes" referencing "videos": delete from videos

Comment: Now I see what you mean: you don't want to recreate the tables so the name of the column `id `remains as it is with the space at the end, right? Why would you want this? You will face the same problems again if you repopulate the tables, although I don't understand how you did it in the first place.

Comment: @forpas you are right, now I see what you mean exactly so I recreated the tables and the problem solved thank you